# Unable to start activity from extended activity given in jar

Tags: java, android, maven, runtimeexception, library-project

I am struggling with weird problem when restarting an old project of mine.

I have two projects:

- Library that provides class that extends standard Activity.
- Application that should use mentioned class as starting activity.

When I try to start the application I encounter an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.bsoftware.catengine.example/org.bsoftware.catengine.example.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "org.bsoftware.catengine.example.MainActivity" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.bsoftware.catengine.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Few info before "just fix the manifest" comments :)

- All worked just fine when it was an android application (one project).
- Application crash when MainActivity extends CatEngineActivity class from provided jar file (it's abstract class that extends Activity).
- Application **do not** crash when MainActivity extends Activity from standard android lib.

Do you have any ideas what went wrong in this case?

**Library project pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.bsoftware.catengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>cat-engine-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Library project manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.catengine.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >
</manifest>
```

**Application pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.catengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>game-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bsoftware.catengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>cat-engine-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Application manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.bsoftware.catengine.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've tried also full package path:

```
android:name="org.bsoftware.catengine.example.MainActivity"
```

---

**Proof of concept can be found here:** https://github.com/mbienkowski/problems/tree/feature/001

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code in MainActivity & CatEngineActivity?

I suspect that CatEngineActivity uses an xml layout file as setContentView()? If so, then the cause is because the android resources are not packaged in your jar file. You have to package CatEngineActivity as an AAR file, which would contain your android resources.

If so, try this starter kit on AAR, and see if it helps. You can ignore the uploading to bintray.

https://github.com/jimcoven/android-bintray-kit

Comment: In my case setContentView() does not use xml file, it uses GLSurfaceView to render OpenGL view. I am not at home right now. I will add some code later :)

Comment: Sorry fot the waiting.. I just edited first post and added link to github with small project.

Comment: I forked your repo, and fixed it. There were some namespace issue with the library and the method loadCreate was called properly after giving it at least a protected access modifier. Look at https://github.com/jimcoven/problems. Just use AndroidStudio to open the solution project.

Comment: Sadly, it's not working for me. I still got the same error at runtime. Anyway, I have a temporary solution which is packaging my lib project as libapk. For everyone: just google apklib maven examples and you will get it ;)